Imported objects has an outline but is invisible when i unselect it
I really haven't tried anything as I did this by mistake, so I just need help lol.
It's invisible besides the outline.




Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

My first thought is that this is a single-sided mesh and you have backface culling turned on in your viewport options.

Please provide more details! How did you import it, what software did it come from and a screenshot of your whole Blender screen might help for a start! Also please share your Blend file as @Jakemoyo says. How do I ask a good question.

so it started from roblox studio and i imported as an obj file, i believe i pressed a button and then this happened. the problem is idk what button i pressed

sure ill try to share

im using blender 4.2 so the isntructions to share are outdated

ill provide a picture for whole blender screen gimme amin

the whole screen is shown now too.

also sorry for the late response i had to do some things

ill be offline for next 5-6 hours so dont expect a response

The instructions to share haven't changed for version 4.2. They're exactly the same as with earlier versions. This is the instruction I usually post for sharing a Blend file:  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. If it's going to be larger than 30Meg it might be better to just share a new file with an import that shows the problem.

@lonesigma253 this file sharing guide has all the relevant information to upload a file with its resources. Please send a file with only the relevant data for this issue, no need to send the whole character if you only have an issue with the head object.

I find it suspicious that you have seemingly twice the same image texture, and one loaded in your Alpha data:

I would try disconnecting that image texture, even delete it if is indeed the same as the one plugged as Base Color.
If that image does have transparency, the texture node's Alpha Mode should probably be set to Straight since it's a PNG, though it's probably not a major issue. But your node tree should look like this:

In some rare occasions the Alpha channel is inverted, in which case you can add an Invert node:

(Obviously this image doesn't need its Alpha inverted).

I first thought it's twice the same image texture, too... but they have two different names, but both have a "diff" suffix. So I suspect none of them have any relevant alpha channel information and they are both just diffuse / color maps. But hard to tell since the question doesn't show how these textures look like. The top image also shows a 2 behind the name indicating it is used twice - but the lower image doesn't have a number so it's not that image.

some imports tend to re-import the same data for each socket it is used for instead of plugging one texture into multiple sockets, I reckon some formats or importer simply do not have any notion of data sharing, or just have one hard-coded nodetree that tries to emulate in Blender/PBR scenario a material format that isn't similar to begin with.

I'm very inexperienced with this software so I will attempt to share it and let you guys tell me in more detail what I did wrong. Thanks for all the help I hope to post the project file of the blender pretty soon.

@Lauloque I don't know much about importers, I'm just used to Blender adding ".001" at the end of the name when it's duplicating things, but here they are named "Handle1_diff.png" and "Handle2_diff.png" which sounds as if they were just like design variants of the "handle" texture. And don't get me wrong, your answer is all fine and got a +1, I just want to add possible other things to consider for the OP to read here, since my comment is not worth a full answer and the "chat" under the question is already long enough.

which button do i press to convert to .blend file

i press file, then external data, then what?

is there any chance that there's a simple button to fix this?

if I import something else like a sword it looks like this

check edited question up above to see

You ask "i press file, then external data, then what?". I assume that's referring to packing the images before sharing the Blend file.  If so, from Blender's File menu, select "External Data > Pack Resources". Then save the file with 'Save as...' and name the file as 'Backup' or similar. Then follow the instructions in my comment above to share the file here.

its uploading at the moment so give it some time

@lonesigma253 Please do not post dozens of single sentence posts by the minute. This site is not a chat room.

I am extremely sorry that I have not responded to you in the correct manner. From this point on I will try to abide to these rules and answer your questions in multiple sentences. Thank you for being so nice about it.

I would also like to say that when I put the .blend file into blend exchange the file has not uploaded. Is there another alternative to sharing the file with you. If so please let me know as soon as possible. Thanks.

I really am sorry for treating this as a chat room. As a show that I really do care I will leave this website. Thank you for all the help it was amazing that all of you tried to help me. Thanks for everything.
